# Parsing PDF Form Data in Browser using Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, pdf, browser

I'm working on a web app that needs to deal with filled PDF forms (converting to a web form is not an option in this situation, since I'm dealing with digitally signed PDFs).

The app needs to upload a PDF, parse the form data from the PDF into JSON, and then upload the PDF as an attachment to a CouchDB server.

Parts 1 and 3 are easy, but I have not been able to find a way to extract PDF data in browser.

As I see it, I have three options:

1. Implement or find a web service (possibly a node service using something like [pdf2json](https://github.com/modesty/pdf2json)). Send the PDF out via AJAX, get formatted JSON data back. I'd rather not do this, since it requires an "extra" web service call, but can if I need to.
2. Find a library that can handle PDF parsing in browser (from blobs/base64-encoded data), and implement using that.
3. Convert a node.js module like pdf2json to something available in browser using browserify or similar.

Has anyone implemented PDF form parsing in browser? Or do I need to implement the web service?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this can get forms, but [PDF.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) already works in browsers.